# Xcode 10 UIBarButtonItem Images Vanish On Storyboard

Tags: xcode, uibarbuttonitem

I am using the latest version of Xcode 10 that's available in the app store.  I keep losing `UIBarButtonItem` images in the designer.  They are visible when the app is run.  I can get the images back by switching the image to a different one and then switching it back again.  This is what it looks like when the images are gone:

[image]

This is what it looks like when the images are visible:

[image]

If I change one image, all of the images on the screen come back.  They will generally stay until I close down and reopen the app in Xcode.

They always display correctly when run on an actual device.  I have tried it on multiple iPads, an iPhone, and every device simulator that I could find.  This is only an issue with images on the designer.

This is how the images are set up in Xcode:

[image]

The 1X image is 24x24, the 2X image is 48x48, and the 3X image is 72x72.  All images that I am using were created in Affinity Designer.  They were all saved as PNG files.  This is a file with the images that I'm using for the checkmark: [Checkmark Files](https://ufile.io/j86tv)

All of the images have the following settings:

[image]

This is what the settings for the `UIBarButtonItem` looks like.

[image]

So far, this is just an annoyance that is happening in multiple apps that I'm working on.  I'd just like to figure out why it is happening and if it is just an Xcode bug.

Comment: You could try deleting your Xcode cache. Probably if your storyboards are really big Xcode just stops rendering everything. (I experienced that a few times). Splitting your storyboard in multiple smaller storyboards could help too.

Comment: I'll give that a try.  The storyboard is small.  It's only four view controllers, and none of them are complex.